# How to properly display a grid

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to change a crystal report. It's a simple grid with header, footer and rows inside a group.

The grid is drawned with lines and inside each square a field is added to display the data. Is this the "normal" way of doing this? I would expect just adding fields with borders would be enought without the need to draw the grid line by line.

I'm using version 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are happy with the kind of display with borders to the fields then you don't need to add the lines to form a `grid` else if you need to be more user friendly then you can add lines.

Either of the option is just a `design` change but not the logic change in the report...

So the answer for this question would be up to the `user requirement and design requirement of the report`

Comment: This mean that the developper drawing the lines of the grid isn't something unusual for crystal report?